# discord.js TypeError "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, discord.js, execute

I get the "Cannot read property 'execute' of undefined"

this is the command in the index.js file

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const config = require("./config.json")
const fs = require("fs")
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./cmds/').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
for(const file of commandFiles){
    const command = require(`./cmds/${file}`)

    client.commands.set(command.name, command)
}
//client.on//
client.on('ready', () =>{
    console.log("The client is ready!")
})
let prefix = config.prefix;
client.on("message", (message) => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) return;

  const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
  const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

  if(command === 'pnig') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
  }
});
client.login(config.token)
```

and this is the one on the ping.js one

```js
const discord = require("discord.js")
module.exports = {
    name: 'ping',
    description: 'pong?',
     execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send('pong!')
    }
}
```

can you tell me whats wrong with my code?

Comment: seems like `.get('ping')` is undefined. Are you sure you're loading the commands correctly? Could you log out each `command` at the top when you're going through the files?

Comment: I don't know I followed a tutorial that they made it like that and it worked for them but that tutorial may be using an older discord.js version
ps: i think discord.js version doesnt matter

Comment: The DJS version matters when working with the library, however this seems to be an issue with your command handler which is mainly NodeJS. If all you did was type this up and have 0 clue of what you're doing we won't be able to work with you to solve the problem.

Comment: I kind of know what it does but maybe the command handler that I'm using is outdated for not putting the commands in a separate file

Comment: I'll try making a test bot and remaking the commands on it

Comment: Are you sure that the ping.js file is in the commands folder?

Comment: It is on the commands folder

Comment: Is your code structured like this link? Also it should be `cmds` folder, not `commands`, since that's what you specified in your code: https://github.com/discordjs/guide/tree/master/code-samples/command-handling/file-setup/12

Answer (score 0):

The error to your code is actually the wrong spelling. You see, you put pnig instead of ping which makes the exception handling say that .execute isn't defined.

```
  if(command === 'pnig') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
  }
```

The simple fix to this is the following:

```
if(command === 'ping') {
        client.commands.get('ping').execute(message, args);
  }
```

Hope you enjoy!